# Can I run a pressure washer without detergent in the tank?

Tags: cleaning, powertools

I've read through two manuals on two different pressure washers and neither of them actually say flat out that you must not run the pressure washer with the detergent tank being empty.  They both say using detergent is optional and that I'm not to use the detergent unless I'm using the lower pressure nozzles.

My main concern is air being pulled in the line from an empty detergent tank. Any thoughts?

Comment: Running pressure washers without water can be bad for them, but I doubt that they also require detergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really worried you could fill the detergent tank with water. But the machines are designed with the knowledge that the detergent tank will run dry from time to time, or folks will forget to fill it... so if the manual explicitly says detergent is optional and there's no metering valve you can turn off (haven't used one, don't know) I would assume this is harmless.

Comment: Yeah... I'm leaning that way myself.  More or less looking to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.  Thanks for confirmation.  :)

Comment: On my unit if I am not using detergent the hose is supposed to be folded and clipped so it won’t suck air.